# How to build two radio button groups in Visual C++ 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, forms

I need to build two groups of radio buttons, so that client can put an answer in groupA buttons and another answer in groupB button. I am not sure how to separate the buttons into two groups. I can only choose one of all. Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By putting them into separate Panel or Group Boxes.  Everything within the panel or group boxes are then grouped together.  So if you have two group boxes, your radio boxes will be grouped by which group box they are in.

MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sefz7fxc.aspx